# Managing context in a JavaScript application

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, mobile, dojo

I am developing a mobile application with the Dojo Toolkit. To give you an understanding of my problem, consider the following application flow:

The start view of the mobile application is a list of entries that represent database instances that are monitored by the application. The user has to select a list entry to get to the views which show all monitored data related to the selected database instance. The application has many views, all of which show some monitoring data. My problem is that I do not know how to let all the views know, which database is selected to retrieve appropriate data from the server.

What would be a good solution for this problem that works well with the MVC pattern? Are there any design patterns that can applied?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to manage a single db instance at a time and it effectively represents a resource within your application then you can add it to the URL (in the hash fragment) and then use a Dojo Router to configure the object in a place that can be retrieved by the views (using some form of registry or right from the URL depending on what you're doing).  It sounds as though any design patterns to note would be in creating consistent interfaces to your database connections if needed (Adapter), but the actual connection tracking should be able to be handled simply by what you're viewing as your Controller.

Comment: I do not know how to add something to the URL. Is this possible in a mobile application?

Comment: look up using a router in Dojo